# socket.io client receives everything except for one emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have got client and server socket.io code. Every message is being received except for one handler: when i send the following to the client:

```
socket.on('loginb', function(login) {
console.log(1);
var a = bedrijven.filter(function(e) {
    return e.bedrijfsnaam == login.bnaam && e.pwd == login.pwd;
});
if (a[0] == null||a.length!=1||a==undefined) {
    socket.emit('wow', false);
} else {
    console.log(2,a);
    socket.emit('wow', a[0]);
}
});
```

everything until "412" will be logged, but the message won't be received. This is how the listener looks at the client side:

```
socket.on('wow', function(login) {
            console.log(26);
 });
```

26 is never getting logged.

The strange thing is: the emitter and the listener are on the same place as other emitters and listeners i have, and work the same. However, this does not work while the rest does.
I also tried replacing `socket.emit('wow', a[0]);` by `socket.emit('wow', 'string');` but no difference.

Comment: What is the 412 you are referring to? It may help to show more of hte code

Comment: @LucasHendren it does not mean anything. It is just so that i know from which line the console.log is fired.

Comment: so what console log is being fired? and what happens when `bedrijven` is null or something.

Comment: Do you get the output from `console.log(2,a);` to prove that you're getting to the socket.emit('wow', a[0]); line of code?  Are you sure that the page that sent the `loginb` message is not reloading or going to a different URL before it has a chance to receive the `wow` message?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty all console logs are being fired. And when bedrijven is null, the if statement results into a different message (false) being emitted but that doesnt work either

Comment: @jfriend00 that indeed is the problem!! the web page somehow is refreshing when the form is submitted. I don't know what causes that though, I already tried preventDefault().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @jfriend00's comment.
Indeed, the problem was that the client did not receive the socket message because the page refreshed after the submit. This was prevented by adding a return statement at the end of the submit function.